# Why is there a vertical gap between adjacent divs when selecting text?

Tags: css, reactjs, contenteditable

I'm making a rich text editor which is like a clone of Google Docs. For reasons I won't get into here, each line in the text editor is wrapped into its own div container. For example, if there's 3 lines of text, there will be 3 child "line nodes" (rendered as an unstyled div) in the text editor. And within each line node there are inline span elements to control styling such as Bold, Italic, etc.

[image: Issue with selection across divs]

The issue I'm having is I can't understand why there is an unsightly vertical gap of whitespace between each line when selecting text over multiple lines. I am using Draft.js for this, but from what I can see it shouldn't make a difference; there's no styling or margins applied. I've even tried making every line div and its span elements exactly the same height but the problem persists.

My guess is this is caused by some native browser behaviour. All I really care about though is: can I "fix" it? I mean, I know it's possible because Google Docs doesn't have this spacing issue when selecting text... But then again it uses a completely custom rendering engine with custom cursors too. Thanks for any suggestions

edit: so a temporary workaround I've found (see image below) is to reduce the height of each div and span to a fixed value (in this case, `height: 16.4px`). But for obvious reasons, this isn't an ideal solution. I'm still looking for a "proper" way to implement whatever styling I want and not have these gaps appear between adjacent divs when selecting text

[image: temporary fix]

Comment: probably line-height, have you looked into that?

Comment: if they are in different div like you are describing, it's probably vertical-align issue. Try to set vertical-align:top

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion below using line-height?

Comment: @zgood I have. Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the selection appearance.
I've also looked at vertical-align. It also has no effect. It seems like only thing visibly affecting selection is the height attribute (see my edited question). Still looking for a real solution though

Comment: try to share a code that reproduce the issue so we can test with you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-draftjs

To replicate behaviour, simply: 

- Type some text
- Press Enter to insert a hard break
- Type some text on the new line
- Select text across both lines.


Notice how there's always a small gap between each line when selecting text? This gap doesn't appear when letting the browser wrap the text natively (but for my purposes, I can't rely on this).

Comment: inline element have this gap, try to change `span` to `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your talking about `line-height` in which you can control the space between two elements / texts.

Try it out below:

```css
div {
  line-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World!</div>

<div>How are ya?</div>
```

Comment: @IvanKaraman Is OP talking about HTML elements and the white space between texts or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately line-height has no effect on the visible selection. Only the height attribute seems to make a difference (see edited question). I'm still looking for a proper solution/answer though

Comment: @Jordan Can you paste a snapshot of your html code for those texts? Just to visually see how its manipulated.

Comment: @LuayWadie Please see the screenshot in my answer for a visual representation of what I'm looking to achieve :)

Comment: @Jordan When I target your div elements and set their line-height to 17px, it solves the problem. Thats not what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions. Turns out this is quite a challenging issue and there's very little (if anything) that can be done with pure CSS. Only the `height` attribute of div or span elements appear to have any visible impact on text selection. Inspecting the Google Docs elements reveals they use their own custom selection engine: [image: gdocs_selection]

Closing this because I at least know how a solution might be implemented now, even if it would be very complex and time-consuming. Thanks again for the suggestions.